# What does "get" mean in this phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A child is eating a birthday cake, and as he leans forward, his T-shirt touches and smears the cake over his t-shirt.

It seems that native speakers would say *you are getting cake on your T-shirt*. What does *get* mean?

Does it mean *to receive*? For example, could the phrase rewritten as *you are receiving cake on your T-shirt*?

I feel it is pretty weird to say that.

There are 27 meanings of *get* in [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get). In this case, *get* could mean *to make somebody/something/yourself reach a particular state or condition*.

> My car got (= was) stolen at the weekend.
>
> get somebody/something + adj. Don't get your dress dirty!
>
> He got his fingers caught in the door.
>
> She soon got the children ready for school.

If it were, then *get cake on his T-shirt* would mean *to make cake reach a state 'on his T-shirt'*.

Comment: Of course I know the answer. To get something on something else, e.g. get mud on your shoe, get egg on your face, is to act in such a way, accidentally, or deliberately, that the first thing adheres to the second. That's a long way of saying it, which is why we have an idiom. Meaning (14) comes nearest, I think: _linking verb to reach a particular state or condition; to make somebody/something/yourself reach a particular state or condition_

Comment: That is, make the shirt reach the state of having cake on it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, if that is the case, then we should say "You are getting your Tshirt dirty", which means "you are making your Tshirt dirty", sounds ok, but "you are getting cake on your Tshirt", which means "you are making cake on your T-shirt", sounds strange

Comment: You are making cake stick to your T-shirt. Not strange.

Comment: @Tom Another native speaker here weighing in to reaffirm this does not sound weird. It’s perfectly normal.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, is it natural to say "**you're getting your Tshirt on the cake**" in stead of "**you're getting cake on your Tshirt**"?

Comment: You could say that. "You're getting the hem of your dress in the mud", to a girl, is possible.

Comment: You could say that "get" is a Swiss Army Knife among verbs.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't mean "to receive". In this sense "to get cake on your t-shirt" means: cake is on your t-shirt and it has made a mess.

Another example is "to get muddy". It doesn't literally mean "to receive mud", it means there is mud on you that you did not intend/want.

If it helps, think of it as "to have cake on your t-shirt"

E.G - "I have cake on my t-shirt", meaning that there is cake on my t-shirt.
So really, "to get cake on one's t-shirt" is the same as "to have cake on one's t-shirt".

"To get" is used mostly for things happening right now, or just happened - which is why you would say "I got cake on my t-shirt", because it would've happened not long ago. You could also of course say "I had cake on my t-shirt", but that is more in the past.

Comment: see oxford dictionary  https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get

There are 27 meanings of the verb "get", then which one does the "get" in "you are getting cake on your T-shirt" fall in?

Comment: @Tom It isn't in that list. I'm a native English speaker and it sounds completely natural. In this sense, perhaps it could be translated as "to have" rather than "to get" if that makes more sense. "I have cake on my t-shirt", therefore you could also say "I got cake on my t-shirt".